# OpenGL ES textures won't show up on some devices

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a problem. So I just put my first game on Google Play. It's a simple bridge building game.

Myself I have Samsung Galaxy S Plus running on Android 2.3.6. The game worked well on my phone, Sony Xperia Ray, HTC Gratia and Samsung Ace.

After putting my game on the market I got few responses telling me that players see nothing but white boxes which means textures don't work for some reason. These phones were LG Optimus Black and Samsung Galaxy S running on 4.0.4. So Android 4.0.4 is custom for Samsung Galaxy S because they didn't release official one.

What to do? All my images are 24 bit PNG and all are power of 2.

Here's how I load them:

```
/** @return texture ID
*/
public int loadTexture(int resource)
{
    int[] temp = new int[1];
    gl.glGenTextures(1, temp, 0);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            resource);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, temp[0]);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // recycle the bitmap
    bitmap.recycle();

    return temp[0];
}
```

And here's the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fizzicsgames.trainthemtocrosslite

Comment: I'd suggest putting some glGetError calls around code blocks related to textures. If you have access to a device obviously it will be much easier. Otherwise if you don't have a device you could throw an exception if you get a nonzero glGetError and rely on your users to submit the bug report and call stack to help you track where the problem's coming from. Unfortunately this might result in 'force close' dialogs for a lot of users, maybe you could have this check turned on optionally so that it doesn't affect all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I'm so stupid. So the problem was caused by placing textures in drawable folder instead of drawable-nodpi. Textures worked correcly on MDPI devices and on devices which support non power of 2 textures (like my Galaxy S Plus). Even though textures were power of 2, they got scaled depending on the screen. So always place your textures in drawable-nodpi if you don't want to create a copy for each of the resolutions.

Comment: why I don't see any image when I put your sample code to `onDrawFrame` of Grafika camera sample project? - https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java#L678

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any shaders?

If so, float precision could lead to h/w dependent troubles.
eg: a float uniform with 1.0 inside it might give you 0 on int(); as if it had 0.99 instead of 1.0.

Post your shader code if you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `glGenTextures`. My advice is don't use it and instead implement your own system of keeping track of textures.

If you debug and check out the values `glGenTextures` is putting into `temp[0]`, you'll see on on some devices it will give you a nice sensible 1, 2, 3 each time you call it. Debug the same code on the other devices and you might see 1000056737, -31895888, etc

Edit e.g.:

```
public class Texture{

    public static int texturecount = 0;


    public void loadTexture(Context context){


        int[] textures = new int[1];
        textures[0] = Texture.texturecount;
        Texture.texturecount.texturecount++;

        //...and bind it to our array
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // etc

    }
}
```

Not a very elegant solution, also probably not thread safe, but it works

Comment: How exactly are you suggesting to create a texture without glGenTextures? That's the only way I know of to create a texture object.

Comment: That will certainly create an error, you have to create a texture object before you can bind it. You can't just make up your own texture indices. glGenTextures is the only way to do this. Note that it's supposed to return an 'unsigned int', so if you cast it to an int and it appears negative there's nothing technically wrong with that, even if it is a little weird.

Comment: Hmm actually I researched a little more and maybe you can create a texture without calling glGenTextures (I though this was in the spec but I can't find it now). Anyway still probably not a very safe idea.

Comment: Well, java lacks an unsigned int. I always though `glGenTextures` was just a convenience method.

I've used my above example and seen no adverse effects (no errors), but then I'm doing relatively unsophisticated textured polys (no lighting, no shaders etc)

You could also do `textures[0] = textures[0]<0? textures[0] / -1 : textures[0];` but that would not guarantee to create a unique texture name.

Comment: Incidentally, on my Kindle fire device, if I target android 2.1 (API lvl 7), and thus use opengl-es 1.1, and call gl.glGenTextures rather than the GLES20.glGenTextures() then it works fine. It is only when targeting API lvl 10 and using GLES20 that I get this problem